# check all of each td of an already generated table

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox for each `td` and when I check the top `td` all other checkboxes in the first column of `td` should be checked. The same with the second, the third and so on. I tried this, but it is not working.

```
$('#chkListF').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find(".chkListSelect").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

The same as the picture when I check firs all `td` should be checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you require you can use `index()` to determine the index of the checkbox in the header, then use the `:nth-child()` selector to find all the checboxes within the column matching that index and set their `checked` state to match:

```js
let $table = $('table');
$table.find('thead :checkbox').change(e => {
  var chkIndex = $(e.target).parent('td').index() + 1;
  $table.find('tbody tr td:nth-child(' + chkIndex + ') :checkbox').prop('checked', e.target.checked);
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
thead { background-color: #DDD; }
td { padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```